# Changind id and name data based on current information when cloning an element

Tags: jquery, html

Content below is to be cloned. What I want to do is, everytime when I clone it with a 'clone' button, the id of select element should change like this in new cloned section:

*When cloned, select element's id and name should appear like this:*

```
<select id="size__0__option" name="designtype[size__0__option]">
<select id="size__1__option" name="designtype[size__1__option]">
<select id="size__2__option" name="designtype[size__2__option]">
```

*HTML code to be cloned but id and name will be changed as shown above in new cloned div:*

```
<div class="need-opt">
   <div class="field-label">
      <label for="size__0__option" class="required"> Size</label>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <select id="size__0__option" name="designtype[size__0__option]">
         <option value="2.50mm (US 1.5)">2.50mm (US 1.5)</option>
         <option value="2.75mm (US 2)">2.75mm (US 2)</option>
      </select>
      <div class="errors"></div>
   </div>
</div>

//Cloned element goes here
//Cloned element goes here
//so on
```

Comment: Could you update your question with your clone code?

Comment: [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) and [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can help you.

You have this inside the body:

```
<div class="need-opt">
   <div class="field-label">
      <label for="size0__option" class="required"> Size</label>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
      <select id="size0" name="designtype[size__0__option]">
         <option value="2.50mm (US 1.5)">2.50mm (US 1.5)</option>
         <option value="2.75mm (US 2)">2.75mm (US 2)</option>
      </select>
      <div class="errors"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<button id="btn1">Clone!</button>
```

And the following function in the head:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $(".need-opt").clone().appendTo("body");
        var clones = $(".field").length;
        for ( var i = 1; i < clones; i++ ) {
            $(".field:eq(" + i +") :first-child").attr("id","size" + i +"");
        }
      });
    });
</script>
```

Every time the button is clicked, the whole div element is cloned and the id of the select element in the cloned container is changed after calculating the cloned containers.